# Strange placement of an indefinite article

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

I have found the following sentence with the strange placement of `an` indefinite article for me. As a non-native English speaker I quite wonder since it has been written by an English speaker indeed.

> He was an in house counsel at The Cooperative League of the USA.

Why is `an` placed before `in`. Personally I would find that meanin otherwise.

Edit: Does it mean the same like this sentence? If so, why it's used `an` instead of `a`?

> He was a/the one in the house...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the article "an" correctly  precedes the adjective [in-house](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%E2%80%93house)  meaning:

> - created, done, or existing within a company or organization. (M-W)

- An in-house counsel, that is a counsel from within The Cooperative League.

Comment: `an in-house` makes sence for me. However why `-` hasn't been used? Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is generally spelled with a hyphen.

Comment: How about adding the source of your quote (or a link)? Maybe just written incorrectly or forgot the -. A spell checker wouldn't catch this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry, I don't feel comforable to link the source of the sentence since it refers to the personal profile of the 3rd party. That's why I also modified the country.